# Angular Directives For Tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to replace

```
<ul class="inner-nav">
    <li><a href="#/a"><i class="icol-layout-select"></i> aaa</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/b"><i class="icol-ui-text-field-password"></i> bbb</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/c"><i class="icol-wand"></i> ccc</a></li>
</ul>
```

With this:

```
<submenu>
<submenu_item icon="layout-select" href="a">aaa</submenu_item>
<submenu_item icon="ui-text-field-password" href="b">bbb</submenu_item>
<submenu_item icon="wand" href="c">ccc</submenu_item>
</submenu>
```

How can this be done with the angular directives ?

Comment: In this case you got to define the behavior for all the tags.

Comment: You cant extend the behavior of `ul` and `li` to some directives that you choose

Comment: Where are you getting this data that you want to transform?

Comment: My answer assumes that what you are really asking is whether you can create directives `submenu` and `submenu_item` that will render as the HTML you include.  If not, please add more information to your question, because it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: marfarma, you got it right :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this this done two ways.  In each case the menu structure is represented as object within the scope, and rendered through the use of directives.  If you need to keep the menu definition within your markup i.e, you need to have `aaa` in the html, neither of these will do what you need, but they might get you thinking in the right direction.

- First way, recursive calls with inline templates, [fully described in this blog post](http://www.grobmeier.de/recursive-menus-angularjs-templates-01082013.html#.Uh4WPhusj2z). Note how the template calls `ng-include` on itself in the list item elements:

  ```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="tree-renderer.html">
  <a href="{{menu.url}}">{{ menuItem.name }}</a>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItem.children" ng-include="'tree-renderer.html'> </li>
    </ul>
  </script>
  ```
- Second way, directive inserting subdirectives, [illustrated in this fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/marfarma/p5uRr/1/). The template for the `parentTreeNavigation` de-minified, looks like this.  Notice how `has-dropdown` depends on the value of `node.children` and the `sub-navigation-tree` element is inserted in every case:

  ```
  <ul id="parentTreeNavigation">
    <li ng-repeat="node in ' + attrs.menuData + '"ng-class="{\'has-dropdown\': !!node.children && node.children.length}">
      <a ng-href="{{node.href}}" ng-click="{{node.click}}" target="{{node.target}}" >
        {{node.text}}
      </a>
      <sub-navigation-tree></sub-navigation-tree>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ```

  if there are no children, the `sub-navigation-tree` directive removes the element:

  ```
  if(scope.tree.children && scope.tree.children.length ) {
     var template = angular.element(//template code);
     var linkFunction = $compile(template);
     linkFunction(scope);
     element.replaceWith( template );
  } else {
      element.remove();
  }
  ```